# Angular 2 ngModel returning [object]

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angular, ionic2, angular2-ngmodel

Just getting started with Angular 2 on an Ionic 2 project.  I have a simple login form:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item></ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="loginData.Email" type="text" value=""></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="loginData.Password" type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

On the backend I have the object

```
export class LoginPage {
  user: User;
  local: Storage;
  loginData = { Email: null, Password: null};

  login() {
    console.log(this.loginData);
  }
}
```

When I type in the username and password though and try to access the data using a console.log the password is showing as:

```
Object {Email: "email - removed", Password: "[object Object]"}
```

Trying something like `this.loginData.Password = String(this.loginData.Password);` results in the same thing.

This also results in the same thing `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.loginData.Password));`

Comment: Try console.log('logindata',this.loginData.Email,this.loginData.Password);

Comment: Doing that gives me `[object Object]`

Comment: It is returning an array. Not sure why console.log('logindata',this.loginData.Password[0])

Comment: `<ion-input [(ngModel)]="loginData.Password" type="password"></ion-input>`

Comment: @JS_astronauts I switched it back, that's actually what it was.  I copied and pasted it after altering it several times trying to get it to work.

Comment: Is it because the type is "password"? Change it to "text" and test it again

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ngModel` is not accepting interpolation as an argument.

[ngModel Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel)

your code should look like:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="loginData.Password" type="password"></ion-input>
```

this seems to work just fine:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="loginData.Email" >


<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.Password" >

<button (click)="login()">login</button>
```

login:

```
loginData = { Email:null, Password: null};

login() {
  console.log(this.loginData);
}
```

Comment: Unless there's something I'm not seeing that's exactly what mine looks like.

Comment: that's because you edited your question, remember? Is it still not working?

Comment: I just got it working, and for whatever reason when I put the values separate instead of in an object it suddenly started working.

Comment: Your example has regular inputs, but since this is an Ionic 2 app I have the ionic-input.  I think that could have something to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find a workaround.  I don't know why this works and the other doesn't, but if I store the values this way

```
  Email: string;
  Password: string;
```

And not in an object it worked fine.

Comment: [In this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LGkhWPQq0WSsi6Aumo2v?p=preview) you can see that your original code is working properly (even though by using the `loginData` object.

Comment: I don't know what to say, I copied that code right from my app.  By all accounts it should work.  I've done lots of Angular 1 apps, and this is close enough that I knew it should have worked.  I have no idea why it kept giving me that result.